# Select Element with index greater than 3 and less than 6

Tags: jquery, selector

i want to select element that its index is greater than 3 and less than 6
ex: `$("td:gt(3)")`  and `$("td:lt(6)")` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just combine the two and it should work:

<del>`$("td:gt(3):lt(6)");`</del>

You can use any number of pseudo-selectors. They will all apply.

However, note that the `slice` answer will be far more efficient than this!

**Update**

The above code is wrong. You need to swap round `:lt` and `:gt` because after the `gt` selector is executed the set of matched elements is reduced and the indexes that `:lt` applies to are different:

```
$("td:lt(6):gt(3)");
```

However, as mentioned above, `slice` will be better, performance wise. If you're interested in how much better that performance will be, I've put together a [quick test](http://jsperf.com/jq-slice-vs-gtlt/2). Here's the results (`slice` is nearly 4 times faster):

[image]

Comment: i tried your sample with a bigger table. Your answer should be right but i have a strange effect. http://jsfiddle.net/gKbKQ/2/ Any Ideas?

Comment: @dknaack - The problem was that the selectors were the wrong way round. `:lt` has to come first otherwise the indexes are wrong (since `:gt` removes elements from the matched set).

Answer (score 13):

make use of `slice(start, end)`

```
$('td').slice(3,6)
```

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)